# DPD Api - generating protocols doesn't work

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, wsdl

I have a problem with DPD Api. I hope someone has been using this web services in your own projects.

Connection and authorization are okey. I can generate packages numbers by using `generatePackagesNumbersV1()` method. It works fine. I get waybills. I also can generate sped labels by using `generateSpedLabelsV1()` method. These labels are in PDF format and I generate the easily.

But... I have a problem with generating protocol by using `generateProtocolV1()` method. Funny thing is that generating sped labels and generating protocols gets the same parameters. But although I send the same parameters to this method - it does not return a PDF file.

This question is directed primerity to people who have been in contact with DPD Api, because it's a slightly specific question. Has anyone used this API? I work with documentation of course but this documentation isn't so good and can't help me. I use VB.NET but it really doesn't matter here.